# How do I cancel Sendgrid in Google Compute?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have been using Sendgrid with Google Compute for about 1 year - just the basic plan GCE sign up with.

I've moved to Postmark due to Sendgrid having deliverability issues.

How do I cancel/delete the Sendgrid account?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps listed below in order to cancel your SendGrid subscription:

1. Navigate to **Marketplace** option in the upper left corner menu of your web console.
2. Select the **Search for solutions** box and enter the **SendGrid Email API** text.
3. Click on the **SendGrid Email API** result option.
4. The SendGrid Email API window will open and you will be able to see the **Change or cancel plan** button used to go to the "Features & pricing" section.
5. Click on the **Cancel subscription** button.
6. Confirm the **Cancel SendGrid Email API subscription** action.

Additionally, I suggest you to take a look on the [SendGrid documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/cancel-your-account/) that contains the instructions required to cancel your account directly on SendGrid; however, this only apply to **paid** subscriptions.